# How to disable OpenVPN from autostarting at boot-up or reboot?

Tags: startup, openvpn, autostart

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS, 64-bit, OpenVPN client 2.3.1

How do I prevent OpenVPN from autostarting at boot-up or reboot?

Comment: According to OpenVPN's website (http://openvpn.net/index.php/download/community-downloads.html), it is recommended to use the current stable release. Specifically the download link for 2.3.1 is http://repos.openvpn.net/repos/apt/precise-stable/openvpn_2.3.1-debian0_amd64.deb  What I did was to right-click the URL and was given the option to save it locally or opened with "Ubuntu Software Center". I chose the latter and installed it with the help of "Ubuntu Software Center".

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You have two options:

- Run:

  ```
  sudo update-rc.d openvpn disable
  ```

  Then you'll have to run `sudo service openvpn start` to manually start the VPN.
- Or edit the file /etc/default/openvpn

  ```
  sudo gedit /etc/default/openvpn
  ```

  And uncomment the line:

  ```
  #AUTOSTART="none"
  ```

  So it looks like:

  ```
  AUTOSTART="none"
  ```

  Then you'll have to run `sudo service openvpn start <vpn-name>` to manually start the VPN. `<vpn-name>` is the config file name without `.conf`.

Comment: Thanks Eric for your help. Can I put more than 10 config files in /etc/openvpn/ ?

Comment: As many as you want. I don't know about its limits, but I think you could have a reasonably high number of config files.

Comment: Eric: If I choose Option 1, ie. to run sudo update-rc.d openvpn disable, if I wish to re-enable autostart, do I use the command: sudo update-rc.d openvpn enable ?

Comment: Yes, `sudo update-rc.d openvpn enable`.

Comment: Thanks Eric for your help. Would you mind looking at the question indicated by the following link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/303203/could-someone-tell-me-whether-my-os-is-communicating-with-the-internet

Comment: Hello @EricCarvalho: thanks for the answer.  Is it some sort of standard ?  Can I add the `AUTOSTART="none"` to another service file (I'd like to prevent `supervisor` from auto-starting) ?  Or is it just for OpenVPN ?

Comment: +1 for `sudo service openvpn start <vpn-name>`

Comment: update-rc.d is init.d related, the new way to process is using systemd. `systemctl is-enabled openvpn@vpn-name` to learn if it's enabled, `systemctl disable openvpn@vpn-name` to disable on startup.

Comment: None of this works for me.  I always have an /usr/sbin/openvpn running after bootup that I have to manually kill, but it comes back on reboot

Comment: Same problem as @Displayname71 - openvpn running again right after reboot.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing on this page helped me, but it was pinned by Google.

The command that fixed my problem:

`sudo systemctl disable openvpn@client.service`

I am running Ubuntu 20.10 with Openvpn v. 2.4.9

RE: https://www.ivpn.net/knowledgebase/linux/linux-autostart-openvpn-in-systemd-ubuntu/

Comment: Oddly, this also does not stop the server from starting after reboot. I ended up having to do `sudo systemctl disable openvpn` to get it to work.