# On Ubuntu 12.04.2, what happens if I disable dnsmasq?

Tags: dns, dnsmasq, caching

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS.

If I issue the following command

```
sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

and change the line

```
dns=dnsmasq
```

to

```
#dns=dnsmasq
```

What will happen? Will I disable or enable DNS caching?

Additional notes:

I have been told that since I am using a VPN service, it would be better for me to do the above.

Answer (score 0):

Extract from http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-disable-dnsmasq-in-ubuntu-12-04precise.html

> The big advantage is that if you connect to a VPN, instead of having
>   all your DNS traffic be routed through the VPN like in the past,
>   you’ll instead only send DNS queries related to the subnet and domains
>   announced by that VPN. This is especially interesting for high latency
>   VPN links where everything would be slowed down in the past.
>
> As for dealing with DNS failures, dnsmasq often sends the DNS queries
>   to more than one DNS servers (if you received multiple when
>   establishing your connection) and will detect bogus/dead ones and
>   simply ignore them until they start returning sensible information
>   again. This is to compare against the libc’s way of doing DNS
>   resolving where the state of the DNS servers can’t be saved (as it’s
>   just a library) and so every single application has to go through the
>   same, trying the first DNS, waiting for it to timeout, using the next
>   one.

So it will not disable it as such, it will be less "safe" and efficient under certain circumstances. Like VPN

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time in writing a detailed explanation. However I don't have a background in IT; hence there are parts of it that I don't understand. Am I right to say that you advise that I do not place the # in front of dnsmasq if I'm using a VPN service to connect to the internet?

Comment: @noob You can disable it without any major issues. If you find that it takes web pages longer to load, I would reactivate it. I have it enabled as disabling it doesn't give me any advantages.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. One of the explanations given by my VPN provider is that if I wish to ensure that all programs tunnel through the VPN and that all programs will be blocked from connecting to the internet if the VPN is disconnected, I should place the # in front of dnsmasq. Is that correct?

Comment: @n00b Yes, my DNS is not blocked in anyway so I don't need to do that, but if your DNS is restricted then definitly disable that feature.

Answer (score 0):

1. dnsmasq launched by NetworkManager doesn't cache query results by default. You can confirm this by running:

   ```
   ps aux | grep dnsmasq
   ```

   You should see `--cache-size=0` as an argument to dnsmasq, which disables caching.
2. If you want to make sure DNS as well as any traffic is being routed through VPN (I believe you do based in [your other question](https://askubuntu.com/q/303203/65926)), you can use `iptables` to accept output traffic destined to VPN gateway and block any other destination. Thus there's no need to touch Networkmanager configuration.